# OpenGL texturing does not work as it should

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glut

I have 128 x 128 px 24 bit bmp file for texture. It's a green square with one vertical line. It loads OK with stbi_image. In initialization are enabled

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
```

and texture parameters are

```
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

I have an object which is made with cubes and cylinders (and some polygons with vertices). I bind texture to one like this to **glut**:

```
glPushMatrix();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex1_id);
glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glTranslatef(-0.5f, 0.2f, 0.05f);
glScalef(2.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f);
glutSolidCube(0.6f);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glPopMatrix();
```

or to **vertices** square:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(-0.03f, 1.26f, -0.35f);
glRotatef(94, 1.0f, 0, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex1);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);  
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-0.3f, 0.4f, 0.0f);  
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-0.3f, 0.85f, 0.0f);  
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(0.3f, 0.85f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(0.3f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
glEnd();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glPopMatrix();
```

I know that glutSolidCube does not generete texture coordinates but apparently with upper glEnables it works just fine. So the texture shows up on the object. Everything looks good at this point.

Problem starts when I change view with lookAt or I translate and rotate object in some path. Then it looks like as texture does not move and rotate with objects but remains static.

[image: Problem]
First: initial view; Second: slightly rotated view (lookAt); Third: slightly translated object

Same thing happens if I will draw that object with vertices. I use OpenGL 2.1 in C++ with glut.

Comment: You've identified the problem yourself, I believe. Without texture coordinates, how could it possibly map vertices to a point in the texture?

Comment: @Dave I hoped that there is some magic way that will make it possible. Solid cube is easy to implement so I am more concerned about solid cylinder implementation. Would it work if I take implementation of glutSolidCylinder and put some texture coordinates in it?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing in wrong way. You have to define texture co-ordinate.
Draw cube by giving vertices and texture co-ordinates by yourself.

```
//first face of cube
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(x, y, z);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(x, y, z);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
glVertex3f(x, y, z);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
glVertex3f(x, y, z);

//and so on for all six face of cube.
```

You must understand how texture co-ordinates works.
Now if you want to draw the cylinder then use `gluCylinder` function look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details. You can map texture on cylinder rendered using `gluCylinder` by using `gluQuadricTexture` function like below.I assume you have loaded the texture.

```
//Create the quadric object to render cylinder 
GLUquadric *quad;
quad = gluNewQuadric();


glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureId);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
gluQuadricTexture(quad,1);
gluCylinder(quad,2,2,3,20,20);
```

You can find the similar example [here](http://www.codeincodeblock.com/2012/05/simple-method-for-texture-mapping-on.html).

Comment: Maybe I haven't described my problem good enough, so I have updated my question. The way with vertices and adding texture coordinates has no effect.

Comment: glutSolidCube is actual problem. It does not generate texture co-ordinate so if you translate or rotate the cube texture won't translate with cube but map in different position.

Comment: I know, I have also modified original function of glutSolidCube and added texture coordinates there. No effect. And even if i draw simple square with 4 vertices and texture coordinates it does not work.

Comment: @drive235: you have to disable automatic texture coordinate generation for the texcoords to have any effect.